# activity selection problem (counter example)

Tags: algorithm

I got two types of activity selection problem, I want to prove that they are not given an optimal solution every time by just providing a counter example.

part1,

Choose an activity A belongs to S which has the smallest duration time.
Form a sub-problem S-prime from S by removing A and removing any activities that are incompatible with A. 
Recursively choose a set of activities X-prime from S-prime.

my counter example:

tasks   s/time   f/time  duration

a    ,     6    ,    7   ,     1

b   ,      0     ,   3   ,     3

c     ,    3    ,    7    ,    4

example output: a

optimal output: b,c

part2,

Choose an activity A belongs to S which overlaps as few other activities
as possible.
Form a sub-problem S-prime from S by removing A and removing any activities that are incompatible with A.
Recursively choose a set of activities X-prime from S-prime.

my counter example:

tasks   s/time   f/time  overlaps

e     ,    2   ,     8     ,   0

b     ,    1   ,     1.8   ,   1

c     ,    5   ,     7     ,   1

d    ,     0    ,    2    ,    0

g      ,   7   ,     8  ,      1

a     ,    0    ,    1.5   ,   2

example output: e

optimal output: a choice of three tasks

I am not sure that my examples are correct, if they are wrong, please provide a correct example so I can know where I was mistaken.

Comment: For me it is not clear what you are trying to solve

Comment: in activity selection problem the tasks are ordered by earliest finish time. so the algorithm will always give optimal solution. but in part 1 above, the tasks are ordered by the smallest duration time. so algorithm will not give the optimal solution for every input. I am trying to prove that by giving a counter example. now I want to check my example , is it wrong or right? @Aldert

Comment: What is incompetible with a, what are the limits of dirstion. I believe you are not giving us the full problem description.

Comment: 1.Input S, the set of available activities.
2. Choose an activity A belongs to S which has the smallest duration time.
3. Form a sub-problem S-prime from S by removing A and removing any ac-
tivities that are incompatible with A.
4. Recursively choose a set of activities X-prime from S-prime.
5. Output the activity A together with the activities in X-prime. those are the steps. if you did not understand. I recommend you read further about activity selection problem. @Aldert

Comment: Dear Patrick, as you are a new contributer I try to help you. You need to ask yourself the question why I am the only one reacting because Stackoverflow is a very active site where people want to help each other. My experience is that when questions are not clear, there is no activity. You also add comments wheere you tell the same again as above. I can only advice you to be clearer in your questioning. I will step out no because I am not able to help you (as you clearly state in your comment). All the best with your problem

Comment: Dear Aldert, my apologies if you got me wrong. however, the question is asked to prove the algorithm will not give an optimal solution for every input. the required is to give a counter example to prove that. so the solution is to give any set of activities as input S which will let the algorithm to give a solution which is not optimal. I gave my answer as an example of a solution. now I want to know if my answer is right or wrong. @Aldert